# Can i delete some old files inside chaindata folder?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, dapps

I am running geth with fast sync, Can i delete some old files inside chaindata folder so that my ssd will have some empty space or it will create some problems ?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it. You will not lose anything, 
And for storage problem run geth in light mode

**geth --syncmode "light" --cache=1024**